# build heap time complexity worst case vs upper bound / tight upper bound

Tags: java, algorithm, heap, time-complexity

[HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/g-fact-85/) it is said that the worst case time complexity of building a heap is O(nlogn) but upper bound is O(n).

How is a upper bound different from worst case time complexity and when one makes more sense over other. 
And is tight upper bound any different ?

Comment: I believe there is some miscommunication somewhere. They probably wanted to say that heapify() is O(n), though at the first glance it appears to be O(n log n) algorithm. Also if implemented naively by doing heap inserts in a sequence the complexity is truly O(n log n). My guess — they are using "worst case" casually not in a math-strict sence.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I do not think it is a typing mistake. Can you please check this out http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/nearly-sorted-algorithm/    Even here in the second solution where they are proposing to use heap they are saying to form a heap of k elements it will take O(k)

Comment: Wikipedia says the same as well as my CS textbook — the complexity of building a heap is O(n). Input data distribution is irrelevant — it's always O(n).

Comment: heapify and build heap are not the same thing. I am talking about build heap here

Comment: Sorry but what's the difference between heapify and build heap?

Comment: {BUILD_HEAP (A)

heap-size (A) ← length [A]
For i ←  floor(length[A]/2) down to 1 do
        Heapify (A, i)}

Comment: Check this out  http://www.personal.kent.edu/~rmuhamma/Algorithms/MyAlgorithms/Sorting/heapSort.htm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68630/discussion-between-walt-and-nick-zavaritsky).

Comment: Building a heap from a set of input is and will always be O(n) (regardless of the said input and the branching factor of the heap - eg. _binary_, _ternary_, ...). You simply misread the link you provided : it says "Although the worst case complexity **looks like** O(nLogn), upper bound of time complexity is O(n)."

Comment: Thanks @Rerito. But that is what I am trying to understand. How is building a heap O(n). Can you please help me understand ? Can we continue on chat ? As comments are piling up which is not recommended or good practice as per rules here at SO. :) Or if you can please help me understanding how building a heap is O(n) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building a heap (also called *Heapify*) is **always** O(n), regardless of the input distribution or the branching factor of the heap (*binary, ternary heaps*...).

You misread the provided link, it states: (emphasis is mine)

> Although the worst case complexity **looks like** O(nLogn), upper bound of time complexity is O(n).

Basically, how does heapify work? (For clarity's sake I'll assume we are using binary heaps)

First let's recall what is the heap condition for a binary heap (using an array A):

> For any i ∈ [0, [N/2], A[i] ≤ A[2i+1] **AND** A[i] ≤ A[2i+2]

*Note: You will usually find the same condition expressed for an array starting at index 1. In that case you just have to "remove" 1, ie. 2i+1 becomes 2i and 2i+2 becomes 2i+1.*

Why is this condition limited to the first half of the heap? Simple, for any i > N/2, neither 2i+1 nor 2i+2 are valid indexes.

**HEAPIFY**
*Input:* An array of N elements
*Output:* An array of the same N elements that enforces the heap condition

```java
void sink(int [] A, int i, int n) {
    int highest = 2*i+1;
    if (2*i+1 >= n)
        return;
    if (2*i+2 < n && A[2*i+2] > A[highest])
        ++highest;
    if (A[i] < A[highest]) {
        swap(A, i, highest);
        sink(A, highest, n);
    }
}

void heapify(int [] A, int n) {
    for (int i = n/2; i >= 0; --i) {
        sink(A, i, n);
    }
}
```

Suppose we have a *complete binary heap*, such a heap contains exactly N = 2<sup>h+1</sup> - 1 elements for a given integer h >= 0. View the heap as a tree. Index 0 is the root of the tree (height 1), indexes 1,2 are the children of this root (height 0), and so on. The height of the tree is the integer h.

The algorithm starts at height h-1. The 2<sup>h-1</sup> elements at height h-1 can be moved at most once while sinking them down. Then, the 2<sup>h-2</sup> elements at height h-2 can trigger at most 2 swaps per element... The root (2<sup>0</sup> element of height 0) can trigger at most h swaps. In the end, the maximum number of swaps to build the heap is :

> MaxSwap = [sum(k=0..h-1, 2<sup>k</sup>.(h-k))](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%28k%3D0..h-1%2C+%28h-k%29*2%5Ek%29) = 2<sup>h+1</sup> - h - 2 ≤ 2<sup>h+1</sup> - 1 = N

The maximum number of comparisons to build the heap is twice the maximum number of swaps.
For any "incomplete" heap, ie. 2<sup>h</sup> ≤ N < 2<sup>h+1</sup> - 1, the reasoning still holds.

Conclusion: Heapify *is* O(N) where N is the size of the heap.

---

### Bonus

A running Java example that builds a Maxheap from an input array : [here](https://ideone.com/zMUSsW)

Comment: @Walt, here, `heapify()` builds a heap. As it has always been meant to.

Comment: And what did I misread ? Didn't get you. I think you are saying the same thing as I said/asked which was how buildHeap(in your world- heapify) is O(n).

Comment: @Walt You misread the link because it __never__ says that the worst case complexity of BuildHeap is O(NlogN), it says it __looks like__ it is.