# Python heapify() time complexity

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, heap, heapq

```
def heapify(A):
    for root in xrange(len(A)//2-1, -1, -1):
        rootVal = A[root]
        child = 2*root+1
        while child < len(A):
            if child+1 < len(A) and A[child] > A[child+1]:
                child += 1
            if rootVal <= A[child]:
                break
            A[child], A[(child-1)//2] = A[(child-1)//2], A[child]
            child = child *2 + 1
```

This is a similar implementation of python heapq.heapify(). It is said in the doc this function runs in O(n). But it looks like for n/2 elements, it does log(n) operations. Why is it O(n)?

Comment: inside the loop, child = child * 2 + 1 until it gets to len(A)

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774237/prove-that-binary-heap-build-max-comparsion-is-2n-2/49781979#49781979

Comment: I don't understand why @typing suggested the child = child*2 + 1. You move from the current node (root) to the child once you have finished, but if you go to the child's child you are actually jumping a level of a tree, try to heapify this array [2|10|9|5|6]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It requires more careful analysis, such as you'll [find here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-complexity-of-building-a-heap/).  The basic insight is that only the root of the heap actually has depth `log2(len(a))`.  Down at the nodes one above a leaf - where half the nodes live - a leaf is hit on the first inner-loop iteration.

### "Exact" derivation

Waving hands some, when the algorithm is looking at a node at the root of a subtree with `N` elements, there are about `N/2` elements in each subtree, and then it takes work proportional to `log(N)` to merge the root and those sub-heaps into a single heap. So the total time `T(N)` required is about

```
T(N) = 2*T(N/2) + O(log(N))
```

That's an uncommon recurrence. The [Akra–Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) can be used to deduce that it's `O(N)`, though.

I think more informative, and certainly more satifsying, is to derive an exact solution from scratch. Toward that end, I'll only talk about complete binary trees: as full as possible on every level. Then there `2**N - 1` elements in total, and all subtrees are also complete binary trees. This sidesteps mounds of pointless details about how to proceed when things aren't exactly balanced.

When we're looking at a subtree with `2**k - 1` elements, its two subtrees have exactly `2**(k-1) - 1` elements each, and there are `k` levels. For example, for a tree with 7 elements, there's 1 element at the root, 2 elements on the second level, and 4 on the third. After the subtrees are heapified, the root has to moved into place, moving it down 0, 1, or 2 levels. This requires doing comparisons between levels 0 and 1, and possibly also between levels 1 and 2 (if the root needs to move down), but no more that that: the work required is proportional to `k-1`.  In all, then,

```
T(2**k - 1) = 2 * T(2**(k-1) - 1) + (k - 1)*C
```

for some constant `C` bounding the worst case for comparing elements at a pair of adjacent levels.

What about `T(1)`?  That's free!  A tree with only 1 element is a already a heap - there's nothing to do.

```
T(1) = 0
```

One level above those leaves, trees have 3 elements.  It costs (no more than) `C` to move the smallest (for a min-heap; largest for a max-heap) to the top.

```
T(3) = C
```

One level above that trees have 7 elements.  It costs `T(3)` to heapify each of the subtrees, and then no more than `2*C` to move the root into place:

```
T(7) = 2*C + 2*C = 4*C
```

Continuing in the same way:

```
T(15) = 2* 4*C + 3*C = 11*C
T(31) = 2*11*C + 4*C = 26*C
T(63) = 2*26*C + 5*C = 57*C
...
T(2**k - 1) = (2**k - k - 1)*C
```

where the last line is a guess at the general form. You can verify that "it works" for all the specific lines before it, and then it's straightforward to prove it by induction.

So, where `N = 2**k - 1`,

```
T(N) = (N - log2(N+1)) * C
```

which shows that `T(N)` is bounded above by `C*N`, so is certainly `O(N)`.

Comment: I do not understand. This does not explain why the heapify() takes O(log(N)).

TH(n) = c, if n=1
worst case when the largest if never root:
TH(n) = c + ? * TH( ? )

how to write the recursive expression?

Comment: Already gave a link to a detailed analysis. It doesn't use a recursive formulation, and there's no need to. And the claim isn't that heapify takes O(log(N)) time, but that it takes O(N) time. Consider opening a different issue if you have a focused question.

Comment: @user3742309, see edit for a full derivation from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

For more mathy folks:
Consider a complete binary tree with L levels, labeled from 0 (root) to L-1. Such a tree has N=2^L-1 nodes. Conversely, a complete binary tree with N nodes has L=log2(N-1) levels.

For any given node at a level l, the bubble/heapify down operation makes L-1-l comparisons. For the total number of operations, we thus need to compute the sum:

[image]

which is equal to

[image]

Note: strictly speaking, the sum goes from 0 to L-2, as the leaves are not to be operated on. However, L-(L-1)-1 is zero, so we can leave the sum upper limit to be L-1