# What is the maximum number of comparisons to heapify an array?

Tags: heap

Is there a general formula to calculate the maximum number of comparisons to heapify n elements?

If not, is 13 the max number of comparisons to heapify an array of 8 elements?

My reasoning is as such:

```
at h = 0, 1 node, 0 comparisons, 1* 0 = 0 comparisons 

at h = 1, 2 nodes, 1 comparison each, 2*1 = 2 comparisons

at h = 2, 4 nodes, 2 comparisons each, 4*2 = 8 comparisons

at h = 3, 1 node, 3 comparisons each, 1*3 = 3 comparisons

Total = 0 + 2 + 8 + 3 =13
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49774237/56778.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accepted theory is that build-heap requires at most (2N - 2) comparisons. So the maximum number of comparisons required should be 14. We can confirm that easily enough by examining a heap of 8 elements:

```
             7
           /   \
          3     1
         / \   / \
        5   4 8   2
       /
      6
```

Here, the 4 leaf nodes will never move down. The nodes 5 and 1 can move down 1 level. 3 could move down two levels. And 7 could move down 3 levels. So the maximum number of level moves is:

```
(0*4)+(1*2)+(2*1)+(3*1) = 7
```

Every level move requires 2 comparisons, so the maximum number of comparisons would be 14.