# How to change priority of an element contained in PriorityQueue in C#

Tags: c#, .net, priority-queue

Given an element contained in a .NET `System.Collections.Generic.PriorityQueue`, how does one change its priority value in-place? If this not possible, then should one `Dequeue()` the item, and `Enqueue()` it again with the new priority value? I don't see anything obvious in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2?view=net-7.0), but asking in case I've missed the relevant details.

Comment: I think you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PriorityQueue` is a data structure which needs to store items in certain way to maintain complexity guarantees, so simple inplace replacement should not be possible in general case. You can  use `Enqueue`/`Dequeue` approach but possibly recreating queue by using `UnorderedItemsCollection` property (processing in via LINQ and "replacing" needed item) and using `EnqueueRange(IEnumerable<ValueTuple<TElement,TPriority>>)` can be a faster approach (requires testing, especially with actual data).

Comment: I wouldn't follow the advice of recreating the queue from scratch each time I had to change the priority of an element, unless the priority changes were extremely rare. Recreating the queue has a significant cost, comparable to sorting an array of the same size (O(n log n)).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias would not enqueue/dequeue approach be almost the same?

Comment: Dequeuing all items one by one until you get the one that you want to update, and then enqueuing them back, should be equally inefficient, unless you are lucky and the relevant item is near the head of the queue.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Actually, building a heap-based priority queue is an O(n) operation, not O(n log n).

Comment: @GuruStron In-place replacement certainly is possible, and not at all difficult to implement in the heap. The difficulty comes in *finding* the node in the heap, which is O(n). But if you know where the item is in the heap, just changing its priority is O(log n).

Comment: @JimMischel would it be in-place replacement? If changing priority is `O(log n)` I assume some moving around would be done.

Comment: @JimMischel the source code of the `PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>` is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs). Every time you `Enqueue` an element it is placed at the end of the `_nodes` array, and then it is compared/swapped repeatedly with the element half-way to the beginning of the array, until a parent with higher priority is found. There are some optimizations for the case that the queue is empty and a range or elements is enqueued in bulk, but overall AFAICS it's an O(n log n) operation.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I am aware of how the queue works. You said that recreating the queue has a significant cost, comparable to sorting: O(n log n). That is not the case. You can initialize the queue with an `IEnumerable` in O(n) time. See [this constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2.-ctor?view=net-7.0#system-collections-generic-priorityqueue-2-ctor(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-valuetuple((-0-1)))))). If you examine the source code, you'll see that it resolves to the `Heapify` method, which is O(n).

Comment: @GuruStron Obviously you can't in general change an item's priority without moving it around. The general idea is that you copy the item, replace it with the last element in the heap, and move that element up or down as required. Then you change priority and re-insert the one you wanted to change. So, yes, things move around. But it does not require rebuilding the entire queue. At worst, it's an O(log n) replacement followed by an O(log n) insertion.

Comment: @JimMischel so the original point stands, in general case in-place replacement of priority is not possible, yes?

Comment: @JimMischel the `Heapify` is [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/916c69153866ca24dcc9b3fc6b4f1d665c7dd829/src/libraries/System.Collections/src/System/Collections/Generic/PriorityQueue.cs#L625). We can easily count how many invocations of the `comparer.Compare` occur for heapifying an enumerable on n elements, and see if the count is proportional to n. I bet 500 rep points that it's not proportional. Are you taking the bet?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yeah, I'd be in on that bet. It's proven that it takes no more than 2N comparisons to heapify an array. Unless the engineer who wrote the method is incompetent, that's how it works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49781979/56778 for some detail.

Comment: @GuruStron Yes, replacement requires some moving around in the heap. However, in no case would it require, as you implied, rebuilding the entire heap. Assuming, of course, that we were modifying the source. As written, the public interface does not allow access to the nodes array.

Comment: @JimMischel my experiment is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qus2lt). The number of comparisons that occur for a source with N elements is around N * 1.3. So it's proportional to the N. The complexity of heapify is O(n). You won the bet! Do you have any preference on which of your posts to offer the bounty? If not, I'll offer it on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774237/prove-that-binary-heap-build-max-comparsion-is-2n-2/49781979#49781979).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I find it interesting that Enqueue all requires so few comparisons. I knew that although Enqueue is theoretically O(log n), in practice it's closer to O(1). But I didn't expect it to be quite that close. Also interesting is that Dequeue all requires somewhat more comparisons than I would have expected. Although .NET does use a quaternary heap, which would result in faster insertions and slower removals than a binary heap.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias As far as the bet goes, I'm fine with calling it good but if you insist I suppose that post would work as well as any other. It is topical, after all.

Comment: @JimMischel yes, I think that the reason that the heapify is so efficient is because the `PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>` is a [quaternary heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D-ary_heap). Each parent node has 4 children, so the 75% of the nodes can be skipped because they are leaves with no children. That was a nice bet to lose. I learned something interesting and useful from this. :-)

Answer (score 3):

The [`PriorityQueue<TElement,TPriority>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) collection is not updateable. Supporting updates would require maintaining more state, and the enqueue/dequeue operations would become slower, so Microsoft opted for releasing a non-updateable version. There is a proposal on GitHub for adding the update functionality, that you could support by upvoting the proposal:

- [Add a priority queue that supports priority updates](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/44871)