# Building priority queue in linear time

Tags: java, priority-queue

There are two ways to build a priority queue:

```
// 1.
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>();  
pq.addAll(collection);  

// 2.
PriorityQueue<Integer> pq = new PriorityQueue<>(collection);
```

- Approach #1 uses the `addAll` method to add each element one by one to the priority queue, so there will be `n` iterations (size of the collection) of the for-loop; and for each iteration there will be a siftUp operation which could take O(log n) time in the worst case. So approach #1 will take O(n log n) time.
- Approach #2 uses the  `heapify()` method which takes O(n) to build the heap.

So it seems approach #2 would be better.

I am not sure about the above analysis. Also, I tested this on a custom object with a custom comparator function, but didn't see any performance improvement. Maybe the amount of data was too small to see any improvement.
Any thoughts on these?

Comment: The second way is better, both because it has better time complexity, but also because the code is more concise (a single statement vs two statements).

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49781979/56778

Answer (score 4):

Your test is likely flawed, because the following test shows a clear difference:

```
class Counter {
    int comparisons = 0;
    
    class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
        final int value;
        
        Item(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Item o) {
            comparisons++;
            return value - o.value;
        }
        
        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Integer.toString(value);
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    static void count(int n) {
        var c = new Counter();
        var items = new ArrayList<Counter.Item>();
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            items.add(c.new Item(i));
        }
        new PriorityQueue<>(items);
        
        var c2 = new Counter();
        var pq2 = new PriorityQueue<>();
        for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            pq2.add(c2.new Item(i));
        }
        System.out.println(n + "\t" + c.comparisons + "\t" + c2.comparisons);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        for (int i = 1; i < (1 << 20); i = (i << 1) | 1) {
            count(i);
        }
    }
}
```

by printing

```
1   0   0
3   2   2
7   8   10
15  22  34
31  52  98
63  114 258
127 240 642
255 494 1538
511 1004    3586
1023    2026    8194
2047    4072    18434
4095    8166    40962
8191    16356   90114
16383   32738   196610
32767   65504   425986
65535   131038  917506
131071  262108  1966082
262143  524250  4194306
524287  1048536 8912898
1048575 2097110 18874370
```

That is, while both approaches use a roughly equal number of comparisons for small lists, they scale differently. To compare this with linear scaling, we can change our code to:

```
    System.out.println(
            n 
            + "\t" + ((double) c.comparisons / n) 
            + "\t" + ((double) c2.comparisons / n)
    );
```

and get

```
1   0.0 0.0
3   0.6666666666666666  0.6666666666666666
7   1.1428571428571428  1.4285714285714286
15  1.4666666666666666  2.2666666666666666
31  1.6774193548387097  3.161290322580645
63  1.8095238095238095  4.095238095238095
127 1.889763779527559   5.05511811023622
255 1.9372549019607843  6.031372549019608
511 1.9647749510763208  7.01761252446184
1023    1.9804496578690127  8.009775171065494
2047    1.9892525647288715  9.005373717635564
4095    1.9941391941391942  10.002930402930403
8191    1.9968257843975095  11.001587107801246
16383   1.9982909113105047  12.000854544344747
32767   1.99908444471572    13.00045777764214
65535   1.9995117112993057  14.000244144350347
131071  1.999740598606862   15.000129700696569
262143  1.9998626703745666  16.000068664812716
524287  1.9999275206137097  17.000036239693145
1048575 1.999961852990964   18.000019073504518
```

confirming that the constructor needs about `2n` comparisons, while repeatedly calling `add()` needs 
`n ((log2 n) - 2)` comparisons.

So, why is `heapify` faster? Its implementation reads:

```
    private void heapify() {
        final Object[] es = queue;
        int n = size, i = (n >>> 1) - 1;
        final Comparator<? super E> cmp;
        if ((cmp = comparator) == null)
            for (; i >= 0; i--)
                siftDownComparable(i, (E) es[i], es, n);
        else
            for (; i >= 0; i--)
                siftDownUsingComparator(i, (E) es[i], es, n, cmp);
    }
```

and

```
    private static <T> void siftDownComparable(int k, T x, Object[] es, int n) {
        // assert n > 0;
        Comparable<? super T> key = (Comparable<? super T>)x;
        int half = n >>> 1;           // loop while a non-leaf
        while (k < half) {
            int child = (k << 1) + 1; // assume left child is least
            Object c = es[child];
            int right = child + 1;
            if (right < n &&
                ((Comparable<? super T>) c).compareTo((T) es[right]) > 0)
                c = es[child = right];
            if (key.compareTo((T) c) <= 0)
                break;
            es[k] = c;
            k = child;
        }
        es[k] = key;
    }
```

At first glance, it seems surprising that heapify should have linear complexity, because it calls `siftDown` `n/2` times, and `siftDown` requires up to `2 log2(n)` comparisons. But let's take a closer look:

In the worst case, heapify involves moving down each node until it is a leaf node. The cost therefore is the total distance of nodes from the leaves of the tree, or

```
n * h
```

where `h` is the average distance from a leaf. What is that distance?

Since a heap is a fully balanced tree, adding a new level of nodes to the tree  adds 1 to the distance of existing nodes, and then adds equally many nodes at distance 0, which halves the average distance:

```
h <- (h + 1) / 2
```

To find what this recurrence relation converges to, we set

```
h = (h + 1) / 2
```

and obtain

```
2h = h + 1
 h = 1
```

That is, the average distance from a leaf in an infinite fully balanced search tree is 1. And that's why `siftDown`, on average, needs constant time, and `heapify` is linear.

In contrast, if we `add()` a node, the following executes:

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (e == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    modCount++;
    int i = size;
    if (i >= queue.length)
        grow(i + 1);
    siftUp(i, e);
    size = i + 1;
    return true;
}
```

where

```
private void siftUp(int k, E x) {
    if (comparator != null)
        siftUpUsingComparator(k, x, queue, comparator);
    else
        siftUpComparable(k, x, queue);
}

private static <T> void siftUpComparable(int k, T x, Object[] es) {
    Comparable<? super T> key = (Comparable<? super T>) x;
    while (k > 0) {
        int parent = (k - 1) >>> 1;
        Object e = es[parent];
        if (key.compareTo((T) e) >= 0)
            break;
        es[k] = e;
        k = parent;
    }
    es[k] = key;
}
```

In the worst case, `add` moves every node all the way to the root. The overall cost therefore is total distance from the root, i.e.

```
n * d
```

where d is the average distance from the root.

To find the average distance from the root, imaging drawing, from each node, a path to the root. Then, the root node is visited for every node that is not the root, each of the 2 nodes beneath are visited (n-3)/2 times, each of the 4 below (n-7)/4 times, and so on:

```
nd = n * 1/1 + (n-1) * 2/2 + (n-3) * 4/4 + (n-7) * 8/8 + ...
   = n + (n-1) + (n-3) + (n-7) + ... + (n - (n/2 - 1))
   = n * log2(n/2) - (1 + 3 + 7 + ... + (n/2 - 1))
   > n * log2(n/2) - (2 + 4 + 8 + ... + (n/2))
   = n * log2(n/2) - n
   = n * (log2(n) - 2)
```

which matches what we measured.

That is, `heapify` is faster because the average node in a fully balanced binary tree is very close to a leaf, but far from the root.

Comment: Thanks for such a good explanation. In my case, I wanted to build the priority queue from Map.Entry objects. I created a new class XYZ implements Comparable which had a custom comparison function. For each entry object, I created a new XYZ object and created a new PriorityQueue<>(XYZList)  
Here the construction of new object for each item of the original list is required because the new custom object has the desired comparison function. 
I am not sure if this could be avoided because it could be really time consuming

Comment: We can specify the comparator in a constructor to the PriorityQueue. But then it seems one has to use the addAll() method. So the ideal approach would be always to have a class implement Comparable and pass the collection of the class as an argument to the constructor. That is the only way to take advantage of the heapify linear time algorithm.  `Just want to confirm if the above observation is correct?` Although it seems weird that one cannot specify the comparator and the collection separately to use the linear time algorithm.

Comment: For a large PriorityQueue, where you know most elements up front, this is indeed the way to go. However, often one uses a PriorityQueue when the elements are not known up front, so that optimization is rarely possible. And if one knows *all* elements up front, a simple `Arrays.sort` is often than creating and draining a `PriorityQueue`. So the case you are describing is rather rare, which possibly explain the oversight in the API.

Comment: There is a problem called finding the top K most frequency characters in a String.  We can build a frequency hashmap and then use a priority Queue of a custom object (with a custom comparator function) to fetch the top K elements in linear time. What do you think is this a good approach? Or better to sort the elements since we know all the elements in the beginning

Comment: The thing is that draining a `PriorityQueue`, i.e. retrieving all elements, is O(n log n), and if you do that, `Arrays.sort` has a slightly better constant factor. If you don't drain the entire `PriorityQueue`, as in your top K example, the `PriorityQueue` is much better than Arrays.sort. Another option would be to only keep the top K elements in the `PriorityQueue`, resulting in an O(n log k) algorithm, which, due to slightly better constant factors, might be a bit faster. But your approach is fine.

Comment: So there are two options if I understand correctly:  `1.` use add() function and keep at most k elements in the PQ  -> This would take O(n log k) time `2.` add all the elements in the PQ using the constructor, where collection implements comparable...which will be built in O(n) time and then fetch k elements each of which could take O(log n) so total would be O(log n) + O(n)   `Approach #1 ` could be fine if k is small, otherwise `Approach #2` will yield a better time complexity always. Need your input on the above. `Thanks a lot`