# Prove that the number of comparisons between elements in binary heap build is at most (2N-2)

Tags: binary-tree, binary-heap

I tried to think about this problem all day, and I'm having difficulties to get the answer. I would appreciate your help.

---

Suppose you have an array H with n elements.
Prove that the number of comparisons between elements in binary heap build is at most (2n-2).

---

pseudo code:

```
BUILD-MAX-HEAP (A)
1 heap-size [A] < - length[A]
2 for i <- Length[A]/2| downto 1
3 do MAX-HEAPIFY (A, i)
```

```
MAX-HEAPIFY (A, i)
1 l <- LEFT (i)
2 r <- RIGHT (i)
3 if l <= heap-size [A] and A[l] > Ali]
4    then largest <- l
5    else largest <- i
6 if r <= heap-size [A] and A[r] > A[largest]
7    then largest <- r
8 if largest ‡ i
9    then exchange A[i] with A[largest]
10   MAX-HEAPIFY (A, largest)
```

---

There is already a post about that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49774237/prove-that-binary-heap-build-max-comparsion-is-2n-2), but I don't understand parts of the answer.

---

#### My thoughts

- `BUILD-MAX-HEAP (A)` is calling `MAX-HEAPIFY (A, i)`  each iteration.
- On each iteration `MAX-HEAPIFY (A, i)` can be called again.
- Each time `MAX-HEAPIFY (A, i)`  is called, there can be up to 2 comparisons.
- On 'leaves'  we don't compare elements since there is no left child or right child (the iteration of `BUILD-MAX-HEAP (A)` don’t  even bother to start with leaves).
- We cant tell if the last level is full of leaves but it doesn’t matter anyway.
- For each node (not the leaves) there are up to 2 comparisons and if `MAX-HEAPIFY (A, i)` is called again there are more 2 comparisons until we get to the lowest level (we go left/right depending which key is bigger).

I'm having difficulties to rephrase what I just said formally and get to the point where the number is 2n-2, so I would love to get your help :)

Comment: This isn't a programming problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: @Alejandro I didn't state it's a programming problem and what is the problem with my question?

Comment: @Lior Precisely that, this isn't a programming question, but this is a programming forum.

Comment: I am the author of the answer you referenced. What parts of the answer don't you understand?